# Is ubuntu touch available for phones with physical keypads?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm using NOKIA X2-01 and want to install Ubuntu. Can I? I guess it is the same for a Nokia 201 or even a blackberry - will it work?

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu phones is not available for the Nokia phone. It has only been made and optimized for the Google Nexus phones and tablets, not Nokia.

Sorry for the inconvenience

Cheers

Comment: Sorry for that, by the way.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices